# Nodejs big file upload restart with dropzone and multer

Tags: node.js, http, dropzone.js, multer

I'm trying to upload file with dropzone.js, nodejs and multer.

So, first, i drag the file in dropzone, and the file is automatically uploading.
Multer create a temp file in /uploads and after I put in the directory.

But the problem is big file. The processing in dropzone stops, multer stop to create the temp file and create an another, and dropzone do the same thing.

```
  Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
   dictDefaultMessage: 'Glissez-déposez vos fichiers ici ou cliquez dans la zone pour déposer un fichier',
   paramName: 'reqFile',
   maxFilesize: 1000,
   maxThumbnailFilesize: 1000,
   //someoptions
   }
```

my router.js :

```
var multer = require('multer');
app.post('/file-upload', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
var uploadFi = multer({
            dest: 'uploads/',
            limits: { 
                fileSize: 8589934592,
                fieldSize : 8589934592,
                fieldNameSize : 8589934592,
                headerPairs : 8589934592
             },
             inMemory : true,
    }).array('reqFile');
   uploadFi(req,res,function(err) {
        console.log('rentre');
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.send('Erreur');
        }  else {
           console.log('go! its ok')

        }
   })
})
```

For the server, i've a timeout to 3600000000ms, so it's not the timeout too..

I have no errors , and i try all possibilities... Please help me !

Best regards,

Pierrick

Comment: Are you sure there are no errors in your browsers console?  It may not be a server side error, and could be that fact the http request is timing out in your browser.

Comment: No, i have no errors.. How to change the http timeout ? Because when I change the server timeout to little timeout, there is an error.

Comment: I think I have the same issue. I upload 20MB video with dropzone and in server side I hold the response until the video is converted using ffmpeg. Dropzone restarts the uplead... :(
Have you find any solutions?